# What is the difference from atan(y/x) and atan2(y,x) in OpenGL GLSL

Tags: opengl, math, glsl, coordinate-transformation, atan2

I've some problems in understanding the result of the function atan in glsl. Documentation is also lacking.

For example I need to convert a vertex to spherical coordinates, transform the radius of the spherical coordinate and then convert it back to cartesian coordinates. I'm using the following transformation on the vertices of an icosphere of radius 2 centered in 0.

```
vec3 to_sphere(vec3 P)
{
    float r = sqrt(P.x*P.x + P.y*P.y + P.z*P.z);
    float theta = atan(P.y,(P.x+1E-18));
    float phi= acos(P.z/r); // in [0,pi]
    return vec3(r,theta, phi);
}

vec3 to_cart(vec3 P)
{
    float r = P.x;
    float theta = P.y;
    float phi = P.z;
    return r * vec3(cos(phi)*sin(theta),sin(phi)*sin(theta),cos(theta);
}

void main()
{
    vec4 V = gl_Vertex.xyz;
    vec3 S = to_sphere(V.xyz);
    S.x += S.y;
    V.xyz = to_cartesian(S);

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * V;
}
```

but the result is different if I use `atan(y/x)` or `atan2(y,x)`. I've put the small `1E-18` constant in order to avoid a pole.

Why this behaviour? I'm supposing that the value returned by `atan(y/x)` and `atan2(y,x)` has different range. In particular in this implementation I think that `theta` should range from `[0-Pi]` while `Phi` ranges in `[0,2Pi]`.

Am I right? Are there more numerically precise implementations of spherical coordinates transformations?

Answer (score 8):

`atan2` properly accounts for all 4 quadrants and can deal with `x==0`.

`atan2(-1,-1)` properly returns `-3/4*PI` while `atan(-1/-1)` would return `1/4*PI`

Comment: So should I stick with atan2 for proper spherical coordinate transformations?

Comment: @linello Yes you should. atan is only useful if you don’t have coordinates, and even then should be used with caution.

Comment: Bizarrely, https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/atan.xhtml actually says for atan(y,x), "Results are undefined if x is zero." It seems likely that's a documentation mistake; atan(y,x) is nearly useless if true.

Comment: @davidvanbrink [the spec document section 8.1 (pdf link)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf#page=144) says "Results are undefined if x and 
y are both 0" which makes it fully useful again.

Comment: Whew! Order is restored.

Comment: there is no `atan2` in OpenGL http://www.shaderific.com/glsl-functions/

Comment: @v.oddou that's because atan is overloaded with a version that takes 1 param and a version that takes 2 params. The 2 param version has the same specification as the typical atan2.